# laravel - Carbon | diffForHumans() shorter version?

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I'm trying to figure out how to shorten the output from a `diffForHumans` method provided by the Carbon library in laravel.

**The default format of `diffForHumans` is something like this:**(*from documentation*)

- When comparing a value in the past to default now:

  1. 5 months ago
  2. 1 hour ago

**But I want the output to be something like:**

1. 1 h
2. 5 mins
3. 5 months
4. 2 years
5. Just Now

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per the source code for `diffForHumans`

```
/**
 * Get the difference in a human readable format in the current locale.
 *
 *
 * @param Carbon|null $other
 * @param bool        $absolute removes time difference modifiers ago, after, etc
 * @param bool        $short    displays short format of time units
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function diffForHumans(Carbon $other = null, $absolute = false, $short = false) {
    ...
}
```

to remove modifiers, pass the second parameter as `true` and to get shortened version of time pass the third parameter as `true`

Source code at

```
vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php
```

Answer (score 8):

Carbon give you an option to remove 'ago'

$time =  \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1)->diffForHumans(null, true)

[image]

if you need use like '1 h, 5 mins', just `str_replace(['hours', 'minutes'], ['h', 'mins'], $time)`;

for `Just now`, you need to specify how long is `just now`.